# Editing Contacts in Contact App error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object

I keep receiving the error

```
Couldnt find <object> without an ID
```

All I am trying to do is allow my users to update their contact's information.

Currently I have my definition of edit and update in my controller are:

```
def edit
 @contact = current_user.contacts.find(params[:id])
end

def update
 @contact = current_user.contacts.find(params[:id])

 if @contact.update_attributes(params[:contact])
   redirect_to @contact
 else
   render action: "edit" 
end 
end
```

And in my view have a form calling object @contact as so

```
<%= form_for (@contact) do |f| %>
<div class = "name-field">
    <%= f.label :name, f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class = "company-field">
    <%= f.label :company, f.text_field :company %>
</div>

<div class = "email-field">
    <%= f.label :email, f.text_field :email %>
</div>

<div class = "phone-field">
    <%= f.label :phone, f.text_field :phone %>
</div>

<div class = "mobile-field">
    <%= f.label :mobile, f.text_field :mobile %>
</div>  

<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

It would be great to get any advice on how I can fix this error :) thanks Tom

Comment: The `edit` action is made for showing the user a form for editing. Update should be performed via the `update` action. Check what you've pasted.

Comment: Hi Jdoe, Thanks for your response. I am trying to show the user a form for a particular contact that they already have so that they can edit the details for that contact - is this not correct? thanks

Comment: What did you try to do with `if @contact.save`? You save the contact which was fetched one line above and then check if your saving was successful. Completely makes no sense in `edit` action. The code looks like `update` action. That's what I meant. But back to your error: it usually happens when someone's trying to call `find` with `nil`. Check your logic of your `edit` action and then check if it gets proper `id` in `params`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `.where` instead of `find`. `find` will raise an `Exception` if it can't find the `id` specified. Alternatively, you can use `find_by_id` which will return nil if it cannot find the object with the `id` that you specified.

EDIT:

- `where` will give you an array of size 1 if you are just giving it 1 `id` or an empty array if it cannot find it
- `find_by_id` will either give you the object with the id specified or a `nil` if you cannot it cannot find the object